# Function to convert Persian(Solar) Persian(Solar) to Persian(Solar) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, sql-date-functions

I need to function to convert  Persian(Solar) Date  to the Gregorian date
A function should be written to receive a solar date in the format (yyyymmdd) and display the equivalent Gregorian date in the output. If the input data was wrong (for example, the month value is more than 12), it will not get an error and display the NULL value in the output.
I don't need to library. I need to this function
for example
1401/11/02 ------2023/01/22 correct
and 1401/13/32---error because month <=12 and day <=31 in persian date
please help me friend .

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample input and expected output, and the data types - are you starting from a string (varchar2) value? And which version of Oracle are you using, as the 'null on error' part is simple in recent versions - are you on 12.1 or 12.2? Your question title also doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hello fazi, welcome to StackOverflow. As Alex pointed out, we need some basic code to help you if you have an error. We need to find which lines generate the error and modify the code to try and fix the error. See: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

In 12cR2 (12.2) and later the date conversion functions can return a value instead of erroring, and [the Persian calendar is supported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/nlspg/overview-of-globalization-support.html#GUID-A6183D94-02BF-4F6A-A20F-4449971BC6A1); so if you are starting from a string value you can just do:

```
select to_date('14011102' default null on conversion error,
  'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian') as result
from dual
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 22-JAN-23 |

... which gives you a date value. If you want a formatted string then convert it back:

```
select to_char(
  to_date('14011102' default null on conversion error,
    'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian'),
  'YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=gregorian') as result
from dual
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 2023-01-22 |

I've specified the calendar in both calls, with the NLS argument, so your session settings don't affect it.

And you can see invalid values returning null with some other values:

```
with cte (persian) as (
  select '14011102' from dual union all
  select '12990128' from dual union all
  select '14001301' from dual union all -- invalid month
  select '14001232' from dual           -- invalid day
)
select persian,
  to_date(persian default null on conversion error, 'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian') as greg_date,
  to_char(
    to_date(persian default null on conversion error, 'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian'),
    'YYYY-MM-DD') as grep_str
from cte
```

| PERSIAN | GREG_DATE | GREP_STR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14011102 | 22-JAN-23 | 2023-01-22 |
| 12990128 | 17-APR-20 | 1920-04-17 |
| 14001301 | *null* | *null* |
| 14001232 | *null* | *null* |

---

If you want to wrap that in a function you can do that with:

```
create or replace function persian_to_gregorian(p_persian varchar2)
return varchar is
begin
  return to_char(
    to_date(p_persian default null on conversion error,
      'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian'),
    'YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=gregorian');
end;
/
```

Or if you're on 12cR1 (12.1) you can use the function to catch and ignore conversion errors (instead of the `default` clause, which doesn't exist yet):

```
create or replace function persian_to_gregorian(p_persian varchar2)
return varchar is
begin
  return to_char(to_date(p_persian, 'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian'),
    'YYYY-MM-DD', 'nls_calendar=gregorian');
exception
  when others then -- or catch specific date conversion codes
    return null;
end;
/
```

---

Or either version of the function can return a date instead of varchar2, and remove the `to_char()` call, e.g.:

```
create or replace function persian_to_gregorian(p_persian varchar2)
return date is
begin
  return to_date(p_persian default null on conversion error,
    'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian');
end;
/
```

... but then the function seems a bit pointless, at least in recent versions.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zH2joCPe)

Comment: tnx alot dear ALEX poole for your anserwing but I want a function for all time with this format  when i call a function and enter the any date I want ....

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can create a function that just makes the same calls to hide the logic - taking a varchar2 argument and returning date or varchar2?

Comment: I want Write a function to receive a solar date in the format yyyymmdd and display the equivalent start date in the output. If the input was wrong (for example, the value of the month is more than 12), there is no error and the NULL value is displayed in the output.

Comment: It does not matter returns date or varchar 2 but its important , Function return a Gregorian date

Comment: OK, the function part is quite straightforward, but I've added that to the answer too.

Comment: tnx alot dear Alex Poole .

Comment: hi Alex , I need help of you . How can I solve this problem with  exception the concept?

Comment: @fazi - I've shown a version with `exception when others then ...` (note that `when others` is often dangerous). If you mean catching each possible date-related exception individually (instead of `others`) then you'd need to declare pragms for them - [see the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-4F0787E6-ABCA-4860-A28E-435C7FE15154). Otherwise, you may need to ask a new question explaining the problem you are having now.

Comment: You have guided me very well, thank you very much, I actually mean using the block exception  according to this block   :BEGIN
<execution block>
.
.
EXCEPTION
WHEN <exceptionl_name>
THEN
  <Exception handling code for the “exception 1 _name’' >
WHEN OTHERS
THEN
  <Default exception handling code for all exceptions >
END;